# change table td border color by assigning class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change border colors for certain parts of a table when a button is clicked. It's a bigger project, but I've been able to recreate the problem here -

http://jsfiddle.net/RZ7UP/8/

CSS:

```
table, tr, td
{
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding:8px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

/*comment this line out and it works*/
#div1 table, #div1 td { border-color:White;}

.colorborder{border:1px solid Red}
​
```

The css style "table, tr, td" is in a css file used by all pages in the project. However, for this particular page, I don't want the black borders which is why I thought to add the style "#div1 table, #div1 td" (note that specifying "border:none" has the same effect). However, adding that makes the jquery manipulation stop working.

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue with css *specificity.* If you use your browser's DOM debugger, you'll see that the style `#div1 td` is taking precedence over `.colorborder`. This happens because an ID is more specific than a class.

Try changing your CSS to read:

```
#div1 td.colorborder{border:1px solid Red}
```

​
You can read w3.org's rules for computing specificity [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). It's good to understand how this works if you're going to do any serious web development with CSS.

---

**A quick introduction to CSS specificity**

In general, here's what you need to know:

- Element names (tag names like `li` and `td`) have the lowest specificity...
- ... followed by classes and attributes (like `[name=firstname]`)...
- ... followed by IDs (like `#div1`)...
- ... with highest specificity going to the inline `style="..."` attribute.

In addition, higher specificity is given to multiple instances of the above. So if one style is assigned to `table td` and another is assigned to `table tbody tr td`, then the second style will win out because more tag names make it more specific.

Of course, you can bump things higher by using `!important` in CSS, but this really shouldn't be used except in special cases (for instance, you want something with `class="red"` to be colored red regardless of where you use it). Otherwise, you'll find yourself using it rampantly throughout your CSS, with one `!important` overriding another according to the rules of specificity, and it's just generally considered sloppy coding anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
#div1 table, #div1 td { border-color:White;}
```

Is referenced by an element's ID (#), which makes it's hierarchy heigher than any other plain class rule.

in order for other rules to work, you need to add the ID selector to them, so that they can override the previous rule's hierarchy.

```
#div1 .colorborder{border:1px solid Red}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg) problem, meaning that the selector that has the white color has more specificity than the red.

check now: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ7UP/12/

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`#div1 table, #div1 td { border-color:White;}`

to

`table#div1,  td#div1 { border-color:White;}`

works too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in CSS I think not in jQuery.

last line of your css with ... 
`#div1 table.colorborder, #div1 td.colorborder{border:1px solid red}`
Reason being is that `#div1` an ID selector will take higher priority regardless if you have the `.colorborder{...}` further down the page...

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ID has an higher specificity as the class